# Datahub SQL Column Lineage With Transformation Logic Snowflake SQL Query

Tags: lineageos, datahub

Suppose I have a SQL in snowflake like this

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
(NAME, ADDRESS, ZIP)
FROM 
SELECT F_NAME+L_NAME AS NAME, 
SUBSTRING(FULL_ADDRESS,1,100),
ZIP 
FROM 
SOURCE_DATA;
```

How can I get lineage in datahub like

F_NAME+L_NAME ----> NAME

SUBSTRINT(FULL_ADDRESS,1,100) ----> ADDRESS

ZIP ----> ZIP

Comment: Hi - you've tagged your question with "lineageos" which is an Android-based operating system, so doesn't seem relevant, but you haven't tagged your question with snowflake-cloud-data-platform which your question is about. What do you mean by "datahub" in this context - as it is a pretty generic word? What have you tried and what specific issue are you facing - getting the lineage in Snowflake, getting the information out of Snowflake and into something else, some other issue?